# Build All productFlavors Automatically in same time

Tags: android, android-studio

I have more than 10 different productFlavors  and whenever I change my project I have to change select build variant and then build apk for each of them.

Is there any way that build all productFlavors  at the same time?

Comment: Have you tried to use gradle for it - first 'clean', and then 'assembleRelease' Both you can find on right side: Gradle -> app -> Tasks  -> build and then first clean, and after this assembleRelease (that should build all products falvours)

Comment: tnx I try it and it works but can I do this without signing apk?

Comment: If you want debug builds, then you can run assembleDebug

Comment: tnx it works perfectlly

Answer (score 1):

You can use gradle for it - first `clean`, and then `assembleRelease` Both you can find on right side: `Gradle -> app -> Tasks -> build` and then first `clean`, and after this `assembleRelease` (that should build all products flavours)

If you want to make Debug builds, then you can use `assembleDebug`